# mod_ruby on apache: Very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, redmine, mod-rails

Even a request from the server itself takes about 7 seconds ( startpage of a "redmine" installation )..

When running ruby under WEBrick the same request only takes miliseconds...

I am absolutely new to ruby, so i have no idea where to start the investgation on this.. Or is the best solution to locally redirect the apache request to a WEBrick server?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make use of your apache setup, you can try [mod_rails aka phusion passenger](http://www.modrails.com/). The installation is straight forward and it performance is better than mongrel or webrick stack.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using mod_ruby, each request starts a new instance of Ruby, serves the page, then discards it. That's stupid-slow. mod_rails, or Phusion Passenger, shares the interpreter and is wicked-fast.